# Convergence of Fourier series in L^{\infty}-norm

Tags: fourier-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

As we know, for $1<p<\infty$, the Fourier series of $f\in L^{p}(T)$ converges to $f$ in $L^{p}$-norm.
But is there any results concerning the convergence of Fourier series in $L^{\infty}$-norm?
Since $L^{\infty}(T)$ is not separable, the trigonometric system fails to form a Schauder basis of $L^{\infty}(T)$, this implies that the Fourier series of $L^{\infty}(T)$-functions fails to converge in $L^{\infty}$-norm. But does the Fourier series of $f$ converge in $L^{\infty}$-norm for every $f\in C(T)$?

Comment: No: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Divergence


Comment: I am voting to close, as this is answered by wikipedia.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I'm mot asking pointwise convergence but convergence in L^{\infty}-norm.

Comment: Convergence in $L^\infty$ implies pointwise convergence.

Comment: It only implies almost everywhere pointwise convergence.

Comment: Partial sums of Fourier series are continuous functions, so you get pointwise convergence everywhere.

Comment: Since there is no need for the convergence to be uniform, the limit need not to be continuous. It is still possible for the Fourier series to diverge on a null set.

Comment: You are confused. $L^\infty$ convergence of continuous functions *is* uniform convergence.

Comment: The Fourier series can even diverge on a null set, so the convergence in $L^\infty$ is different from the convergence in $sup$-norm.

Comment: Acky : if you first throw away a set of vanishing Lebesgue measure, then you have uniform convergence to a function. This function is continuous as a uniform limit of continuous function. Then you can extend the function etc. No ? I have not checked the details.

Comment: No one is disputing that Fourier series can diverge on a null set. Katznelson's example showed that it must be so. The point is that for a *continuous* function, knowing its behaviour on a set of full measure suffices to prescribe it every where. In other words, $$ \sup_{x\in T} | S_n(s) - S_m(s)| \leq \| S_n - S_m\|_\infty $$ for all partial sums $S_N$. So $L^\infty$ convergence does imply pointwise (and hence even uniform) convergence. What you should think is that for any $a > 0$, the set $A_{n,m}$ of points in $T$ such that $|S_n - S_m| > a$ decays to measure zero as $n,m\to\infty$, but

Comment: in principle it can be that there exists some $a$ such that the measure of $A_{n,m}$ remains positive for all $n,m$. 

Comment: Short version: the canonical map from the Banach space $C({\mathbb T})$ into the Banach space $L^\infty({\mathbb T})$ really is injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Fourier series of continuous functions would converge in $L^\infty$, then, by the Uniform Boundedness Principle, the operator norms in $C(\mathbb{T})$ of the partial Fourier series operators $S_Nf(t):=\sum_{n=-N}^N\hat{f}(n)e^{int}$ would be uniformly bounded. You can find, for example in Katznelson book, a proof of the fact that such norms diverge logarithmically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find the answer in P191 "Classical Fourier Analysis",second edition, Loukas Grafakos

Comment: NO, it's not the answer to the question of mine. The result of duBois Reymond is well known and is a easy corollary of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem. But it is about pointwise convergence, not convergence in $L^\infty$-norm.

Comment: but as the function and the partial sum of the Fourier series are all continuous functions, if we have $L^{\infty}$ convergence of partial sum, then we can get contradiction?